# How install a extension in postgresql before creating the models in django?

Tags: django, postgresql-9.3, django-migrations, ltree

Using django 1.8 + Postgres 9+, I have models with custom PG datatypes (like ltree). Creating de database from zero fail because

```
CREATE EXTENSION ltree;
```

is not executed. I try with a empty migration, but that run *after* the models creation. Exist a way to run sql before the models creation?

Comment: You can manually edit the initial migration to add this custom sql. BTW why is this tagged postgresql 8.4?

Comment: I do that (in the initial migration) but is not run before the model creations. I delete the PG database for a full recreation before run python manage.py migrate

Comment: how about clearing out the migrations for that app, creating a new migration that only contains the create extension and then ./manage.py makemigrations to create a new migration for table creation (will have to clear up the entry in django_migrations though)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this is unanswered for long, and maybe now you already have figured out the answer. But I'm posting just in case someone gets a little bit of help from this.

***For extensions that are available in Postgres***

If the extension is one of the defaults that are available with Postgres, then you can simply create first migration as this, and then load other migrations.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import HStoreExtension

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    run_before = [
        ('some_app_that_requires_hstore', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        HStoreExtension(),
    ]
```

Notice the use of `run_before`. It is the exact opposite of `dependencies`. Alternatively, you can make this migration as say 1st one and load all others after this using `dependencies`.

In case this migration fails to create an extension because of privileges issues, then you can simply use the `superuser` and `nosuperuser` in Postgres to temporarily provide privileges for the current user to run migrations like:

```
ALTER ROLE user_name superuser;
# create the extension and then remove the superuser privileges.
ALTER ROLE user_name nosuperuser;
```

***For third-party extensions that are not available in Postgres***

For third-party extensions, you can use run_python, to load the extension for you like:

```
from django.db import migrations


def create_third_party_extension(apps, schema_editor):
    schema_editor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION my_custom_extension;")


def drop_third_party_extension(apps, schema_editor):
    schema_editor.execute("DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS my_custom_extension;")


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('venues', '0001_auto_20180607_1014'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_third_party_extension, reverse_code=drop_third_party_extension, atomic=True)
]
```

Alternatively, you can just have them as a part of your deployment scripts instead of migrations.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. How can I add this to the existing schema? Do I just create a random migration file? I am getting this error when I added custom file. `django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration main.0001_initial is applied before its dependency main.0000_extenstion on database 'default'.` @sanyam-khurana

Comment: Whatever new migration file you create should have dependency according to you previous migration which seems the `0001_initial` migration in your case.

Comment: Also for 3rd party extensions not available, I found it simpler to add another Class for your extension in the ````django.contrib.postgres.operations```` file that mimics out-of-the-box extensions available. Then you can easily treat this as out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the extension on the template database, and when new databases are created (like when running tests), the new database will copy that template and include the extension.

```
psql -d template1 -c 'create extension if not exists hstore;'
```

Answer (score 0):

For django 3+ you can use `migrations.RunSQL`:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('some_app_that_requires_hstore', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('CREATE EXTENSION ltree;'),
        migrations.AddConstraint(
            ...
        ),
    ]
```